# How to put nested php array into java script?

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

I have this code

```
        $ref = addslashes(htmlspecialchars(json_encode($value)));
        echo '<script>var message_store_'.$key.'=$.parseJSON('.$ref.');alert(message_store_'.$key.');</script>';
        echo '<div class="message_entry" id ="message_entry'.$key.'" onclick="open_up_thread(\''.$ref.'\',\''.$key.'\');">'.$key.'</div>';
        $recent = end($value);
        echo '<div id ="recent_message_log_entry'.$key.'"><div>'.$recent['message'].'</div><div>'.$recent['date_posted'].'</div></div>';
```

I am facing a problem storing the array in a global JavaScript variable.
But i have the div onclick event working fine the array got converted to what i wanted and the function open_up_thread is parsing the encoded JSON object fine.

I need to keep track of that array before onclick event is fired(after onclick its easy as its already converted).

So how do i achieve storing the php array to a global javascript object as JSON in php.

And any reason why i have onclick working but not the variable

thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you're tyring to mix php and javascript, which isn't possible. JS is client side, whereas php is server side.

Comment: No, OP is not, he shares that array using json. This is perfectly valid.

Comment: You don't need to `addslashes` or `htmlspecialchars` on  `json_encode` output. Try removing that and running your code again.

Comment: You also don't need to parse the JSON on JavaScript side. It is valid Javascript.

Comment: @AlainTiemblo I stand corrected.

Comment: @Mike W it doesnt work with out addslashes or htmlspecialchars on json_encode i tried boss!!

Comment: @Bart Friederichs Hi if i alert with out parsing it just shows string but if i parse it shows object which is what i wanted to i did use JSON parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `$.parseJSON()` function and remove `htmlspecialchars` and `addslashes`:

```
$ref = json_encode($value);
echo '<script>var message_store_'.$key.'='.$ref.';alert(message_store_'.$key.');</script>';
```

JSON is a format that can directly be parsed to a variable.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
is this because i have spaces in array elements?

Comment: Same error again sir.
do you want me to post the html that i am getting on browser?

Comment: var message_store_qo@gmail.com=[{"message_id":"330","message_from":"3","message_from_email":"wo@gmail.com","message_to":"2","message_to_email":"qo@gmail.com","message":"hi","date_posted":"2013-08-06 14:27:04"}];

Comment: how to escape @ because i need that in name

Comment: not easily. You can try escaping with some kind of regex. But you're almost there

Comment: on what line do you get the error? And paste the new output you have now without the `@` . Also the `.` is not legal in the variable name. So remove that as well!

Comment: Thank you sir!! It worked after i deleting the @ and . from alert as well

Comment: how would i get to store @ and . ?

Comment: You can store them . but you can't have them in the variable name (key)

Answer (score 0):

Put single quotes around the $ref in `echo '<script>var message_store_'.$key.'=$.parseJSON(\''.$ref.'\');`

```
$ref = json_encode($value);
        echo '<script>var message_store_'.$key.'='.$ref.';alert(message_store_'.$key.');</script>';
        echo '<div class="message_entry" id ="message_entry'.$key.'" onclick="open_up_thread(\''.$ref.'\',\''.$key.'\');">'.$key.'</div>';
        $recent = end($value);
        echo '<div id ="recent_message_log_entry'.$key.'"><div>'.$recent['message'].'</div><div>'.$recent['date_posted'].'</div></div>';
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: That may be some typo error. Check the line number and line that the error occurs in.

Comment: sir i did check! its in the line where message_store is being assigned to $.parseJSON(\''.$ref.'\');

Comment: Edited the answer.. try now.. $.parseJSON is not required as the output of json_encode is a valid object.